# how to run 2 if statements simultaneously

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, gpio

i have this code and i'm having a problem with it, when the first if statement is working i can't run the second if statement until the last delay finishes and if the second if statement starts i can't run the first statement and vise versa

so what would be the be code to fix this problem i tried def and while but couldn't get to what i need

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time 
import lcddriver


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
display=lcddriver.lcd()
GPIO.cleanup()
# Configure Relay Output Pins
Relay1=31
Relay2=32

GPIO.setup(Relay1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Relay2,GPIO.OUT)


# Configure Relay Input Pins
IN1=29
IN2=15


GPIO.setup(IN1,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(IN2,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)



while (1):
    if  GPIO.input(IN1)==1:
        GPIO.output(Relay1,1)
        display.lcd_clear()
        display.lcd_display_string("   Input 1   ", 1)
        display.lcd_display_string("     Opened     ", 2)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        GPIO.output(Relay1,0)
        display.lcd_clear()
        time.sleep(1)
    if  GPIO.input(IN2)==1:
        GPIO.output(Relay2,1)
        display.lcd_clear()
        display.lcd_display_string("   Input 2   ", 1)
        display.lcd_display_string("     Opened     ", 2)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        GPIO.output(Relay2,0)
        time.sleep(1)
        display.lcd_clear()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not in a multi-process program
Only one thread of your CPU is used
If you really need to run the two if statements at the same time you should change your code so that the parts you need to run is in the same if statement

```
If condition1:
    Part1
If condition2:
    Part2
```

Will become

```
If condition3:
    Part1
    Part2
```

It's an algorithmic error, you shouldn't seperate your block within two if(s)

I can suggest to use a function like this

```
def do_part_two():
    Part2

def do_part_one():
    Part1

If condition1:
    Part1
    do_part_two()
If condition2:
    Part2
    do_part_one()
```

But still I encourage you to change your if so that you're in my first solution case

**N.B:**
You can create  a delay function and call it whenever you need

```
def delay(x):
    time.sleep(x)
```

Comment: thank you for the replay, can you please do me a favor and write the code for me using the code given, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with the library you use
I just gave the logic
You can do anything with it sir ^^

Comment: no worries at all, i could figure it out by using mutliprocessing library.